# php date time is not same

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

```
$date = '11/14/1997';
$unix_birthday = strtotime($date);
echo $unix_birthday;
```

**The result is: 879487200**

When I run this code:

```
$time = 879487200;
echo htmlspecialchars(gmdate("Y/m/d", $time));
```

**The result is: 1997/11/14**

How Can I fix this? The dates are not same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo htmlspecialchars(gmdate("Y/m/d", $time));` should be `echo htmlspecialchars(gmdate("m/d/Y", $time));` its just a matter of format

Comment: @AliyevRauf - the format.  month-day-year or year-month-day... for options, [see the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo htmlspecialchars(gmdate("m/d/Y", $time));
```

Comment: Yes it worked but I am trying your code the result is : 11/13/1997

Comment: Please look to this: http://ideone.com/m5mTem
My code is working too. But on my server shows 1997/11/14

Answer (score 0):

```
echo htmlspecialchars(gmdate("m/d/Y", $time));
```

Just rearrange m/d/Y where m = month, d =day and Y = year

**Demo**

http://ideone.com/2R93OZ

Comment: If you write it as Y/m/d the date will be formatted and generated as year first then month then day so 1997/11/14. Make sure you use a capital Y.

Comment: can you give me a fiddle which your code is working?